# when I am changing code in symfony its not reflecting in browser (orangehrm)

Tags: php, symfony-2.3, orangehrm

I am trying to change the code in the Orangehrm built under the symfony framework. My task is to change certain things in the attendance reports i.e. in attendance report all employees are shown including the past employess. I want that in daily atendance reports past employees should not come. 
I have made changes in the file name `Attendancedao.php` which is inside the folder

`symfony/plugins/orangehrmattendanceplugin/lib/dao/attendancedao.php`

I have made change in the funcion

```
 public function searchAttendanceRecords($employeeIds = null, $employeementStatus = null, $subDivision = null, $dateFrom = null , $dateTo = null )
 {

 }
```

there I have added a condition to not fetch employees having the termination id as not null.

but there is no change is reflected in the front end part of it.
even for testing I had deleted the files completely but still project ran successfully.
although I am sure these is the only file to make any changes in the needed situation. but if there is any change please suggest that too.
I am assuming it is some cahce file from background rns that code. please suggest if there is any process to change or clear the cache so the changes are reflected in the front end.

Comment: you are making changes to a file that belongs to a vendor ?   if so,  this is VERY wrong    -   if not, just clear your app/cache folder

Comment: how shall I clear.can u be more specific that where i can cache and delete so..and what it means vendor files???

Answer (score 0):

indeed, you should not modify vendors files...
There is a way to clear cache : delete app/cache content, or you in a terminal : `$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` (or --env=dev)

=>http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to clear the cache in Orange. Delete the following folder after making a backup of orangehrm: `OrangeHRM/symfony/cache/orangehrm`. This folder and its contents will be regenerated with the current environment the next time you load orangeHRM in the web browser.

But I dont think this is the issue as I have made many changes to the `LeaveRequestDao.php` and other Dao files in the orangehrmLeavePlugin before and the changes where instant on front end.

Could you post the complete contents of the `searchAttendanceRecords($emp...)` function with your added code. Also, check the orangehrm.log. After doing the action that should call your new code check the log file for an error entry, its found in orangehrm/symfony.log. To see if your getting any error messages.